# The microphone does not work on my Optiplex 3080 mini

Tags: audio, microphone, dell-optiplex

As the title says, The microphone cannot be detected on the universal audio port. I've been struggling with this issue for a while now since all computers at my company use this and have not been able to fix this issue as of now. I've tried installing the Waves MaxxAudio Pro Driver and it still does not fix the issue.